# How to convert regular expression from java to php

Tags: java, php, regex

I have regular expression:

```
(9[0-5[7-9]]{1}[\d]{10})|([0-2]\d{11})
```

This expression work for java, but doesn't work for php.
Help me to convert in to php

```
// true
System.out.println("123456789012".matches("(9[0-5[7-9]]{1}[\\d]{10})|([0-2]\\d{11})"));
System.out.println("973456789012".matches("(9[0-5[7-9]]{1}[\\d]{10})|([0-2]\\d{11})"));
System.out.println("000456789012".matches("(9[0-5[7-9]]{1}[\\d]{10})|([0-2]\\d{11})"));

// false
System.out.println("12345678901".matches("(9[0-5[7-9]]{1}[\\d]{10})|([0-2]\\d{11})"));
System.out.println("963456789012".matches("(9[0-5[7-9]]{1}[\\d]{10})|([0-2]\\d{11})"));
```

Comment: I trying to use this '/(9[0-5[7-9]]{1}[\d]{10})|([0-2]\d{11})/'

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it should only exclude `96`... from the starting `9` ones, thus can be simplified to:

```
^(?:9(?!6)|[0-2])\d{11}$
```

For PHP need to wrap the pattern into [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

[Test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/yN2kL7/2)

Comment: what about `12345678901`? in question it is marked as a false.

Comment: oh i get it, it has not enough digits :P

Answer (score 0):

Your Java regex can be rewritten as:

```
9[0-57-9]\d{10}|[0-2]\d{11}
```

Since Java `String.matches()` makes sure the whole string matches the regex, you need to anchor the regex in PHP to get the same effect:

```
'~^(?:9[0-57-9]\d{10}|[0-2]\d{11})$~'
```

Comment: Thank, I make it like this:
/(9[0-5,7-9]{1}[\d]{10})|([0-2]\d{11})/

Comment: @user2264941: Please don't add `,` between 0-5 and 7-9. It makes the regex incorrect. And I don't understand why you don't take any of my advice.

Comment: Fix it, remove symbol ,